# Transferring NUTITEQ account to CARTO

Tags: carto, user-account

I am using a NUTITEQ API key and now I want to use CARTO mobile in my App.

It says the app bundle is already used, but this is via my NUTITEQ account which I think is probably now inactive.

Can I transport the NUTITEQ account to CARTO?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to transfer the account. You get the error in carto.com, right? Currently the only way would be to use another app bundle ID.